# Is every positive sequence that tends to zero monotone decreasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove/disprove: We have a positive sequence $a_n$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ so the series $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} (-1)^na_n $ converge.

It's very similar to Leibniz alternating sum test but I think the statement is false so I'm trying to find a counter example. If there's a positive sequence that tends to zero but isn't monotone decreasing then the alternating sum test won't work, thus the series does not converge.

Comment: The alternating series test only gives a _suficient condition_ for convergence.

Comment: Take, e.g., $a_n=1/n^2$, $n$ odd; $a_n=1/n$, $n$ even.

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ you mean there can be an alternating series that doesn't satisfy the alternating sum test but still converge ?

Comment: @GinKin Yes. Try to find a convergent series similar to the one given by David Mitra.

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ $a_n=1/n^2$, $n$ is odd, $a_n=0$, $n$ is even. I see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

First off, failing the alternating series test doesn't imply that the series doesn't converge.

The example you gave is perfect: $\displaystyle a_n = \begin{cases}1/n^2 &\text{if $n$ is odd}, \\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is even}. \end{cases}$.

Notice that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ but $a_n$ is **not** monotonically decreasing (it jumps up and down from $1/n^2$ to $0$).

However $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_n < \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty$ and hence converges.

---

Now, to disprove the statement in question, define $\displaystyle a_n = \begin{cases}1/n^2 &\text{if $n$ is odd}, \\ 1/n & \text{if $n$ is even}. \end{cases}$.

It is immediate that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Notice that $$\displaystyle \sum_{n \text{ odd}} a_n = \sum_{n \text{ odd}} \frac{1}{n^2}< \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ and $$\displaystyle \sum_{n \text{ even}} a_n =  \sum_{n \text{ even}} \frac1n  = \frac12 \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac1n = \frac12 \cdot \infty = \infty.$$ Therefore $$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1
)^n a_n = \sum_{n \text{ even}} a_n - \sum_{n \text{ odd}} a_n = \infty - \text{ finite positive number} = \infty.$$